# time complexity regarding elses?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, nested-if

i can not find any information about it so i hope you can help me.
the question is regarding nested else-ifs in for loops and time complexity calculating.

the general code i have is:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  if(___);
  else 
  {
    if(___);
    else(___);
  }
}
```

every (___) is a complexity if O(1).
the problem im having is i keep getting confused at how to calculate the not-simplified big-O complexity, because of the else and nested if-else.
is it O(n*1+1+1+1)? or maybe O(n*1+1*(1+1))? 
how do i aproach it?

Answer (score 0):

Since `O(1)` is asymptotically insignificant compared to `O(n)` it doesn't matter which one you use, the result will still be `O(n)`.

If you did worst case it would be `O(n)` * `[O(1) + O(1) + O(1)]` = `O(2n)` => `O(n)`, as for each iteration of the loop you are doing each of the conditionals, so it is `n * 2` operations.

Comment: for lerification, i take a look at the first if and see its a O(1), and then i add to it the first else, which i know consists of 2 O(1) statements (the 2nd if and else), and therefore my final calculation is O(n) * [O(1) + O(1)]?

Comment: well so each if has a condition (which itself has complexity) and operations that follow. Say each condition has a complexity of `O(1)` and each if/else's code has a complexity of `O(1)`. Worst case would check if (`O(1)`), go to the corresponding else, do the else operation which is another if condition (`O(1)`), then go to last else which would be `O(1)`. So worst case would be `O(1) + O(1) + O(1)` for each iteration